# pypi package tag not same as the latest version

Tags: python, git, packaging, pypi, twine

I uploaded a [package](https://test.pypi.org/project/pyflyby3/1.6.2/) to test.pypi.org with the version `1.6.2` and put the git tag 1.6.2 on the latest commit.

[image]

However, the image under **Project description** is showing `1.6.1` - which is another git annotated tag in the master branch.

[image]

Could someone help me understand why the version under **Project description** was not updated?

I am using `twine` to upload to pypi. Steps:

```
 python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
 python3 -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/  dist/pyflyby3-1.6.2.tar.gz
```

Comment: Assuming this project has been packaged with _setuptools_, the solution should be in the `long_description` argument to `setuptools.setup` or in `setup.cfg`, which most likely is some kind of README file. It'd be possible to answer your question if you showed the content of that.

Comment: The README.rst file for this project contains: `.. image:: https://badge.fury.io/py/pyflyby.svg \ :target: https://pypi.org/project/pyflyby/` which obviously refers to the most recent stable release of [`pyflyby`](https://pypi.org/project/pyflyby/) on the _production_ instance of _PyPI_, and not `pyflyby3`_test_ instance.

Comment: @sinoroc yes `setuptools.setup` is used. The `version` argument is correctly set to `1.6.2`. The `long_description` is nothing but the README file visible in the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `README.rst` file for this [project release](https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/80/4bc5e07dd77c677274267896ac5cfd5920c790d4911230c819dd505094e5/pyflyby3-1.6.2.tar.gz) contains:

```
.. image:: https://badge.fury.io/py/pyflyby.svg
    :target: https://pypi.org/project/pyflyby/
```

which obviously refers to the most recent stable release of [`pyflyby`](https://pypi.org/project/pyflyby/) on the *production* instance of *PyPI*, and not `pyflyby3` on the *test* instance.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Seems like we can't have a tag for `test.pypi.org` using `https://badge.fury.io/for/py`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, this (there would be not much point to refer to a test instance anyway), and the fact that the project name is wrong.

Comment: I uploaded to the prod pypi.org but it still shows 1.6.1 - https://pypi.org/project/pyflyby/. It could be that the image is cached on `badge.fury.io` end. https://badge.fury.io/py/pyflyby.svg still points to the 1.6.1 version at https://d25lcipzij17d.cloudfront.net/badge.svg?id=py&type=6&v=1.6.1&x2=0

Comment: Probably some cache somewhere. Looks fine to me.